# dictionary of key, value from two lists without repeating items from either list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am learning python and wanted to try and make a little script to handle "pulling names from a hat" to decide who has who for Christmas. I have no doubt that there is a more efficient way than this, but it works for the moment.

My issue is that it's taking a very inconsistent amount of time to complete. I can run this once, and it spits out the results instantly, but then the next time or few times it will just spin and I've let it sit for 5 minutes and it's still not complete.

Looking for some advice on why this is occurring and how to fix to make sure it doesn't take such a long time.

To start, I have two identical lists of the same names and then I shuffle them up:

```
fam1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7"]
fam2 = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7"]
fam1_shuffled = random.sample(fam1, len(fam1))
fam2_shuffled = random.sample(fam2, len(fam2))
```

I then have a dictionary of name pairs that are not allowed (so that husband: wife and wife: husband from the same house don't pull each other's names for example):

```
not_allowed_pairs = {
    "name1": "name4",
    "name4": "name1", 
    "name3": "name6", 
    "name6": "name3"
}
```

Then I have the function itself:

```
def pick_names(list1, list2): 
    pairs = {}
    gifters = list1
    used_names = []
    while len(pairs) < len(gifters): 
        for i in range(len(list1)): 
            if ((gifters[i] != list2[i]) & (list2[i] not in used_names)): 
                k = gifters[i]
                v = list2[i]
                if (k, v) not in non_allowed_pairs.items(): 
                    pairs[k] = v
                    used_names.append(v)
    return pairs
```

Finally, just to separate it out, I have the following function to print out who picked who.

```
def print_picks(pair_dict):
    for k, v in pair_dict.items():
        print(f"{k} picked: {v}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The crucial part of this algorithm is how we pick the receiver. For example, if the gifter is *name1* then the receivers list should not contain *name1*, or *name4* (because of the `not_allowed_pairs`). Here is my code:

```py
import random


def print_picks(pair_dict):
    for k, v in pair_dict.items():
        print(f"{k} picked: {v}")      


def remove(lst, *elements):
    """Return a list with elements removed."""
    reduced_list = [
        element
        for element in lst
        if element not in elements
    ]
    return reduced_list


def pick_names(list1, list2, not_allowed_pairs):
    # Make copy to avoid modification of the original
    list2 = list2.copy()

    pairs = dict()
    for gifter in list1:
        receivers = remove(list2, gifter, not_allowed_pairs.get(gifter))
        receiver = random.choice(receivers)
        pairs[gifter] = receiver
        list2.remove(receiver)
    return pairs


def main():
    fam1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8"]
    fam2 = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8"]
    not_allowed_pairs = {
        "name1": "name4",
        "name4": "name1", 
        "name3": "name6", 
        "name6": "name3"
    }

    pairs = pick_names(fam1, fam2, not_allowed_pairs)
    print_picks(pairs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
name1 picked: name7
name2 picked: name3
name3 picked: name2
name4 picked: name5
name5 picked: name4
name6 picked: name8
name7 picked: name1
name8 picked: name6
```

Now this algorithm is not perfect: There will be time when we run out of names. For example, given name1, name2, and name3: name1 picked name2, name2 picked name1, then name3 got left over. These are edge cases, and I just run the script again.